# Does it make sence to use an instance id as a feature to train a ML model?

Tags: python, machine-learning, time-series, prediction

I'm trying to predict a footbal outcome by training a ML model.
My data have team IDs along other feature.
The question is, will it make sencce to feed it (the model) the team IDs or will it treat it as a numerical value.
I believe training a seperate model for eatch team will not make much sence since its performance depends on the rival team. therefore to include the rival team features as well and includes its ID.

Comment: If you feed it as a numerical value it does not make sense. If it is a categorical it does since I guess you somehow have to specify which is the team. So just OneHot encode the feature

Comment: Thank you for your answer. It seams logic to OneHot encode the names (Ids). But it would be alot of features to add since there is alot of teams. My data does not concern only teamA vs TeamB but also other teams that played againts TeamA or TeamB

Comment: How many different teams you have? @Chérif

Comment: Above 20000. but to predict one game, i'm considering giving it the data that concern each team. meaning TeamA and his previous rivals and TeamB and his previous rivals also for about a year. 
It would be 100 team IDs at large.

Comment: jsut because it is a number, it's not a numerical value. I.e. team 10 is not 10times team 1. Using team id will be a problem if you want to use your model for other teams not in your dataset, it might also be a problem because it might be colinear with some other variables

Answer (score 0):

> Does it make sense to include the team ID as a feature in the model?

In most case yes. To your point, about a team's performance being correlated with rival teams (or with the performance of a team last year from which a star player had been transferred into the new team), the only the model can pick it up is if it is able to keep track of which data comes from which team, so you would have to add the team ID as a categorical variable in order to do so.